# How to make a POST request to api

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code to make a connection to a `.Net Web API` however in my understanding I am using the `POST` method because I am using `HttpPost` object but the api says:

```
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
```

My Code:

```
private boolean POST(List<NameValuePair>[] nvPair) {

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String UrlString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvPair[0], "utf-8");
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(apiBaseUri + UrlString);

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvPair[0]));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String respond = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        Log.d("MSG 3 > ", respond);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sending HTTP Post request

```
String UrlString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nvPair[0], "utf-8");
            URL url = new URL(apiBaseUri + UrlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "android");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String response = readResponse(connection);
```